# Download a ZIP using cURL is getting corrupted

Tags: php, curl, server

I am trying to download a ZIP file from a provided url. When I go to the URL directly, my browser instantly downloads a ZIP file containing a CSV file that I need. But I need an automatic download of this ZIP file. So I was trying to download the ZIP with cURL.

But every time I try to download it with cURL, it seems like the ZIP file is corrupted. I always get the following error when I try to open the ZIP file:

> No archive found. Archive has an unknown format or is corrupted.

Also the file has only 59 KB when I download it with cURL, but is larger when I download it with the browser. The ZIP file downloaded with browser has a file size of 2.7 MB.

This is my current code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
set_time_limit(0);

$source = "url";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 

curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "118151_alloy_nl.rar";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried opening the file with a text-editor? seems to me that the server doesn't deliver the file you request but some error-response.

Comment: Title: "Download a RAR", Text: "I am trying to download a ZIP", which one is it? And how do you try to open that file?

Comment: @VolkerK Sorry, I am trying to download a ZIP. And when it arrived I am trying to extract it with WinRAR. And then the error arrives.

Comment: try using `wb+` mode for writing to the file or directly pass file pointer to curl like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I opened the ZIP file with a text editor and I just got the page of a website, so indeed not the file I wanted. What am I doing wrong then ?

Comment: If it is a zip, then why `$destination = "118151_alloy_nl.rar";`?

Comment: In your code, `$destination` is a RAR. Is it the same as the URL you go to directly in the browser to download, or is the URL `118151_alloy_nl.zip`?

Comment: do you have to login to access the file? is your link correct?

Comment: @VolkerK Indeed that was wrong, i changed rar to zip now. But I still get the same data, just a webpage instead of a file.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes I believe the link is correct, because I directly copy it from the URL where it succeeds. And the login data is in the link. That is the reason I am not posting the link.

Comment: Could be the user-agent. Or cookies. Or ...